# python match lists

Tags: python

Removing supersets when sublists are compared with other sublists in a list_of_lists

Input:

```
  my_list = [['cat','bat'],['sat','rat','mat'],['cat','bat','hat'],['pat','mat']]
```

Here ['cat', 'bat'] is a subset of ['cat', 'bat', 'hat'] So I need to remove the superset ['cat', 'bat', 'hat'] from my_list

Desired Output should be:

```
  my_new_list = [['cat','bat'],['sat','rat','mat'],['pat','mat']]
```

I found a similar thread but could not implement the same code for comparing sublists with one another. Can anyone help me with this?

```
  def match(my_list[],my_list[]):
       matches = set(my_list[]).issuperset()
       return [remove(my_list[]) for sublist in my_list if matches (sublist)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to filter a list by a criterion. Turn the data into a type where the criterion can easily be applied like `set` and apply a List Comprehension:

**listmatching.py**

```
def get_top_sets(mylist):
    """ Returns a list of minimal subsets of the original"""
    m = [set(sublist) for sublist in mylist] # Convert into list of sets
    # If there is no element t that is a subset of s, add s to the new list
    return [list(s) for s in m if not any(not s == t and t.issubset(s) for t in m)]
```

Here we test whether there exists any element that is a subset of of the current element. If the check fails, there is no such element and we have an element that is not the subset of any other, and we can add it to our new list.

**Interpreter:**

```
>>> from listmatching import get_top_sets
>>> my_list = [['cat','bat'],['sat','rat','mat'],['cat','bat','hat'],['pat','mat']]
>>> print get_top_sets(my_list)
[['bat', 'cat'], ['rat', 'mat', 'sat'], ['pat', 'mat']]
```

We convert it back to the original `list` type inside the list comprehension.

Comment: ` def match(mylist):
          mylist = [set(sublist)for sublist in mylist]
          mynewlist = [list(subset) for subset in mylist if not any(not subset == testset and subset.isubset(testset))]
          return mylist`

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this:

```
from itertools import permutations

my_list = [['cat','bat'],['sat','rat','mat'],['cat','bat','hat'],['pat','mat']]

for a,b in permutations(my_list,2):
    if set(a).issubset(b):
        my_list.remove(b)
print my_list
```